# How to perform mod(%) operation in smarty?

Tags: smarty

I'm a newbie to Smarty. I want to do a mod operation on an array element in smarty. Following is the code snippet I'm trying to implement:

```
{if {$que_seq_no}.{$sub_ques_no+1} % 10 == 1}
```

Could you please help me to correct it? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if

Comment: Thx for ur suggestion @DavidBrabant. I've gone through it. Could you please help me to correct the above code snippet?

Comment: doesn't `{if $que_seq_no[$que_seq_no+1] % 10 == 1}` work?

Comment: I suspect it's not the mod that's the problem, but this bit: `{$que_seq_no}.{$sub_ques_no+1}`; I don't think curly braces work that way. `$que_seq_no[ $sub_ques_no+1 ]` might be what you're looking for.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Answer to question title

The modulo operator is `%` and has also alternation `mod`.

For more on recognized qualifiers in smarty reffer to docs: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.if

### Answer to your problem

So as you now know, your modulo operator is correct.

From what I can guess from your syntax, you are probably trying to access value of array by array index.

For accessing array items you have 2 possibilities:

1. Access by array key - syntax: `$arrayVariable.key`
2. Access by array index - syntax: `$arrayVariable[index]` (index is an int number) 
   So in your case: `$que_seq_no[$sub_ques_no+1]`

If you are trying to access object property:

it is similar to access by array key, but operator is `->` so syntax is: `$objectVariable->propertyName`

For more on this reffer to smarty docs: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.variables.tpl

#### What probably confused you

I think you got a bit confused by usage of `{}` (curly braces)

 - they are used to wrap the **whole** smarty expression - so from that it implies that they can't contain any other `{` or `}`.

A pretty example taken from smarty docs is:

```
{if $name == 'Fred' || $name == 'Wilma'}
   ...
{/if}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are using acceptable syntax for the mod operation. I am pretty sure you're using incorrect syntax with the variable `{$que_seq_no}.{$sub_ques_no+1}`. Have you tried `$que_seq_no[$sub_ques_no+1]`?